# Issue while using com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminService in application

Tags: java, websphere, aspectj, websphere-7

I am using below classes in Aspectj instrumentation code to get cellName, NodeName and Processname from WebSphereApplication Server. I understood from IBM documentation that WAS provides below classes for such use cases.

```
com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminService;
com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminServiceFactory;
example
/*

    AdminService adminService = AdminServiceFactory.getAdminService();
    cellName = adminService.getCellName();
     nodeName = adminService.getNodeName();
    processName = adminService.getProcessName(); 
*/
```

for compiling I am using `com.ibm.ws.admin.jar`

but when I am starting WAS with -javaagent:. websphere is throwing **`classnotfoundexception for AdminServiceFactory.

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of or at least extremely similar to [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28451808/1082681). As I already said there, with so little detail you should not expect a good answer. You have a problem, don't you? So why don't you help the SO community to help you solve it?